# Create macro for deleting pre-existing buttons and then adding new ones in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on Excel-VBA where I am trying to create a macro which would delete buttons in the selected area and create new buttons. While I have created the code for deleting buttons in selected region, I can't create new buttons as the new button number is different from one recorded in the macro. Any way out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code with create a button on the first sheet of an Excel file and name it according to your liking. Just make sure that there is no button by that name yet on that sheet.

```
Public Sub NewButtons()

Dim btnNewButton As Button

With Worksheets(1).Range("F5")
    Set btnNewButton = .Parent.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, 100, 50)
End With
With btnNewButton
    .Caption = "Press me!"
    .Name = "NameOfTheButton"
    .OnAction = "NameOfTheSubToCallWhenPressed"
End With

End Sub
```

The new button is align to cell F5 (which you can also adjust to your needs). The width and the height of the button are 100 and 50 respectively.

I hope I understood you correctly and this resolves your problem.

Comment: This helps, but delete function no longer works as it shows error of being unable to get the TopLeftCell property of the button class.

Comment: This should work: `Worksheets(1).Buttons("NameOfTheButton").TopLeftCell.Address` or `If Worksheets(1).Buttons("NameOfTheButton").TopLeftCell.Address = "$F$5" Then Worksheets(1).Buttons("NameOfTheButton").Delete`